# Yii2: how to stop inbuilt id generation by yii2 for each field in form

Tags: yii2

When i am adding form to view & specifying parameters as

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'form_name', ['options' => ['id' => 'formName', 'name' => 'formName']])->textInput(); ?>
```

But, when i run in the browser & check for view page source, there it shows me

```
<input type="text" id="submitform-form_name" class="form-control" name="SubmitForm[form_name]">
```

this disturbs my javascript calling for field input. How to stop yii2 from generating its own id???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing options to `ActiveField`. If you want override `id` and `name` attributes, pass them in [textInput()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#textInput%28%29-detail) options like so:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'form_name')->textInput(['id' => 'formName', 'name' => 'formName']) ?>
```

Generated html output will be:

```
<input type="text" name="formName" class="form-control" id="formName">
```

**Note that after that client validation for this attribute will stop working and that attribute won't be massively assigned.**

Comment: would like to have chat for a serious error i am facing since from last month. are you available?

Comment: Alternatively, I believe there's an option to set `inputOptions` when passing values into `ActiveField`, but if it can be helped, @arogachev's answer is the better option.